# How can I make Resharper wrap very long lines properly?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, code-formatting

Resharper's code formatting is generally fine, but it seems completely broken when dealing with very long lines. For example look at this piece of code:

[image]

I do want some kind of line wrapping, but it should look ahead and indent less if necessary to avoid ridiculous amounts of line breaks. Something like this would be great:

[image]

Is there any way to make Resharper do this?

Comment: I'm also irritated by this. One way to get somewhat better formatting is by placing a new-line after your first "=" (i.e. start a new line at Fakes.ReportClientAssignmentsRepository).

Comment: @telewin: That's pretty much the same thing I keep doing, but if I forget to add my line breaks before hitting ctrl-e-f, the formatting is messed up and stays that way unless I manually remove a lot of line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex Berezoutsky of Jetbrains has suggested to turn off "Indent array, object and collection initializer" checkbox in the "ReSharper | Options | Languages | C# | Formatting Style | Other" dialog. It's not ideal IMO for shorter lines, but it does look much better on very long code lines.

I guess it's the best workaround for this problem at the current time.

Answer (score 0):

I admittedly haven't plugged your code into my IDE to try it so I don't have exact setting values for you, but have a go at tweaking the line wrapping options in R# options.

- Go to Resharper | Options
- Under Languages expande C# and then Formatting Style, click on Line Breaks and Wrapping
- Review the settings in that category

Comment: I already did... several times. But I could not find any setting that would make the indentation wrapping work correctly.